# PHPUnit Testing the Send Method parameters from SwiftMail

Tags: php, phpunit, swiftmailer

Maybe I'm over complicating this, but I have an Email Object that is being called by another class and the Email class uses an instance of Swift Mailer.

```
$email = Email::instance();
$mailer = $this->getMock('Swift_Mailer', array('send'), array(new \Swift_NullTransport()));
$email->setTransport($mailer);
$mailer->expects($this->once())
    ->method('send');
$model->sendEmail('user_email@test.com');
```

As is above I can easily test if the the send method was called and correctly affirm that the email is being sent, but, I need to test the subject from the Swift Mailer Message that is being sent with the mailer.

```
$email = Email::instance();
$mailer = $this->getMock('Swift_Mailer', array('send'), array(new \Swift_NullTransport()));
$email->setTransport($mailer);
$mailer->expects($this->once())
    ->method('send')
    ->with($this->equalTo('new email subject'));
```

Obviously that doesn't work and a lot of errors are thrown.

Any ideas of how I can test this?

Comment: An another approach is to put the email's sending logic into a method write a functional test for this method and when is needed to send an email you can just mock this method.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

Instead of testing the Swift Mail contents, I'm mocking the model and testing the params being passed to the function that call the Email Object class.

Definitely not pretty,but it will solve the specific issue above.